# WFP C# ListView databinding for dynamic updates

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, uwp

Help please.

I am updating an application that needs to display alarm data dynamically in a ListView.
Currently when data arrives the alarm condition is evaluated and displayed graphically
in XAML controls using DependencyProperties in Custom UserControls and INotifyPropertyChanged
events in the MainViewModel. This works fine to change the color of the fields
as required with the updates pulled through live.

My task is to implement some alarm logic such as user acknowledgment of active
alarms etc. To this end I'm writing the alarm details to a LocalDB instance and
displaying them in a ListView page. This page populates ok when I load up the
dB with a _Loaded event when I navigate to the page however when on the page I
can't seem to get the data to update live using the same method that updates the
graphic colors!

I have created class to hold LV-style string data that populates from the Db so
there shouldn't be an issue with that. I don't want to post too much code,
but can anyone tell me if I should be populating each field of the ListView with
individual data bindings or can I rely a data binding that can be passed the whole
LV alarm class?

```
    public class LVAlarmItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Raised { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Ack { get; set; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Alarm> AlarmList = new ObservableCollection<Alarm>(); //Real alarms from Db
    public ObservableCollection<LVAlarmItem> LVAlarmItems = new ObservableCollection<LVAlarmItem>();
```

// LV items populated from Db

```
        foreach (Alarm alarm in _viewModel.AlarmManager.AlarmList)
        {
            lVAlarmItems.Add(new AlarmManager.LVAlarmItem() { Name = alarm.AlarmName, Status = alarm.ValueStatus.ToString(), Raised = alarm.RaisedTimeStamp.ToString(), Id = alarm.Id.ToString(), Ack = alarm.Ack.ToString() } ); 
        }
        AlarmList.Alarm_ListView.ItemsSource = lVAlarmItems;
```

This XAML works for the _loaded event:

```
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Raised" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Raised}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Acknowledged" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Ack}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
```

It feels like my LV should be populated directly with Alarms to be honest, but I thought I'd try to get it working with the simpler structure first. New to MVC which doesn't help, hope my question makes sense.

More info: I'm trying to bind my main XAML page to the user control:

`<Controls:AlarmList x:Name="AlarmList" MainAlarmList="{Binding MainAlarmList}"  Width="1350" Margin="60,63,100,100" Background="{x:Null}" Loaded="AlarmList_Loaded" Height="600" />`

where in the cs of the user control I have is :

```
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MainAlarmListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MainAlarmList", typeof(ObservableCollection<AlarmManager.LVAlarmItem>), typeof(AlarmList), new PropertyMetadata(OnPropertyChanged));
        public void Render()
        {

        }

        public ObservableCollection<AlarmManager.LVAlarmItem> MainAlarmList
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<AlarmManager.LVAlarmItem>)GetValue(MainAlarmListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MainAlarmListProperty, value); }
        }
```

Screenshot:[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnbQ4.png)

Comment: How and where are you trying to update the data?

Comment: I added more info to the original post if that helps. The MainAlarmList should update on the generation of a new alarm and then trigger a refresh as an Observable Collection/Dependency Property, that's the general idea.